# Ignore TypeError during For Loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to "ignore" TypeErrors during a For Loop, but I would like to pass an empty string value to my variable when I do come across a TypeError or a property that does not exist. I have tried some try/catch with TypeError, but I'm not quite sure what to do with the catch. Any help is appreciated...

My obj

```
theObj = [ 
    {
        name:"Billy",
        age:"30",
        level:"10"
    },
    {
        name:"Jimbo",
        age:"25",
        level:"8"
    },
    {
        name:"Ralph",
        age:"37"
    },
    {
        name:"Rita",
        age:"23",
        level:"3"
    }
]
```

Loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < theObj.length; i++) {
    const levels = theObj[i]['level']
    console.log(levels)
}
```

console

```
10
8
undefined
3
```

What I would like to see

```
10
8

3
```

OR

```
10
8
Null or some other value like DNE, N/A
3
```

Comment: console.log(levels || 'Null');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem

```
for (var i = 0; i < theObj.length; i++) {
    const levels = theObj[i]['level']
    console.log(levels ? levels : "")
}
```

Comment: This might actually work, I wasn't specific enough in my code example.
The real problem is ['color'] doesn't exist.
`const levels = theObj[i]['level']['color']['value']`

Answer (score 1):

Try `theObj[i]?.level`, like:

```js
const theObj = [ 
    {
        name:"Billy",
        age:"30",
        level:"10"
    },
    {
        name:"Jimbo",
        age:"25",
        level:"8"
    },
    {
        name:"Ralph",
        age:"37"
    },
    {
        name:"Rita",
        age:"23",
        level:"3"
    }
];

for (let i = 0; i < theObj.length; i++) {
    const levels = theObj[i]?.level;
    console.log(levels)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
const levels = theObj?.[i]?.['level'] || ""
```

?. make sure that the parent is defined and if not it will return undefined

Comment: still getting an undefined with changes

Comment: @doppis undefined is like the variable wasn't defined (yes I said that) you if you don't want to display this state in the console.log use this 
```console.log(levels || "")```